# Problems moving data between ActivX List boxes (and corresponding worksheets) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I’m working on a project to keep track of people in a shelter.

**BACKGROUND**

In a dashboard are five different ActiveX List Boxes. Every List Box represents a location (Location A, Location B, Location C etc.). Every List Box gets its data from a sheet called “Sheet A”, “Sheet B”, “Sheet C”, etc.
A person is registered with a UserForm. The person’s data is saved in “Sheet A” (total 46 cells with data) and the most important information is visible in the “Location A” List box (10 columns). All list boxes/Sheets have the same setup

When double clicking on a row in the List Box, an “Edit” UserForm opens where you can edit the person’s information. After closing the form the person is still in the same location (Row number/List box/Sheet) as before but the data is updated.

In the “Edit” form is combo box called “Current location”. With this you can chose where to move the person (Location A, Location B, Location C, etc.). A person can move to/from all list boxes

If a person is in “Location A” and you want to move him/her to “Location C” the data is saved to “Sheet C” with VBA code. 
Eg:

```
    Sheets("C").Range("Anchorpoint_C").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = FirstName_TxtBox

    TargetRow = Sheets("Engine").Range("AJ6").Value + 1               ‘AJ6 contains a COUNTA formula that keeps track of the last populated row in the sheet)
```

Then VBA deletes the row the person was in (in Sheet A)
Eg:

```
    Sheets("A").Rows(Sheets("Engine").Range("AJ31").Value + 2).Delete   ‘AJ31 stores the row number where the persons data is located. It loads in to the cell when the Edit form opens.
```

At last the List boxes are updated.
Eg:

```
    With Worksheets("Dashboard").OLEObjects("Location_A_ListBox") 
    .ListFillRange = .ListFillRange 
    End With
```

**PROBLEM**

When just saving the data to the new location (the data in two sheets) Excel gets very sluggish. After saving 5-7 persons in new locations (data still in two sheets) Excel crashes.

When saving the data to a new location AND deleting the row in the original location, Excel crashes.

I have tried to “manually” cut and paste data between the worksheets. But when updating the list boxes they contain empty rows, but in the corresponding sheet are no empty rows.

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

I am new to VBA and use Excel 2010, Swedish version.
I haven’t declared any variables, simply because I am no sure exactly how to do it. Except for the "moving person part" everything runs smoothly anyway. My plan was to declare variables afterwards, when I tidy up the code.
[I enclose a picture of the ListBox properties, in case you can spot anything  wrong there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koows.jpg)

Thanks for taking your time to read this.

[Image of EDIT FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgxvb.jpg)
[Image of EDIT FORM with (With ComboBox Current location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPQAl.jpg)

Comment: I have to assume you are using a loop. Can you please provide the full code. My initial hypothesis is that you are looping on a full column - in which case you would want to `Intersect()` with the sheet's UsedRange to limit the iterations to the actual range that contains data.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for taking your time.
I’m not using a loop… I thought I could do it as simple as I described; Save the data to the new location (Sheet) and then delete the information in the old location (deleting the row), and that’s it…  I didn’t know it had to be that complicated. 
I’m a novice to VBA and not very familiar with loops. I just have a very basic knowledge of loops. What would a loop do in my case? What would the code look like?
Do you have the time to explain, or do you know any good website where I can read myself.
Thanks again
Ulf

Comment: I see, so you are just making 1 update at a time? I don't think there is enough information provided to assess the "sluggish" issue. This could be due to large amounts of data on the sheets, or lots of calculations refreshing when something like adding a record occurs; especially if you are using any array formulas (or formulas that act on arrays like `COUNTIF()`). I also think your data structure, as you have described it, is not efficient. I would put everything in 1 table, with a location field. But again, not enough to go on in terms of providing guidance there.

Comment: The sluggish issue is the strange part.  I use same code when saving data from the “Registration"- and “Edit form”, to a “Location sheet”. But it is only sluggish when saving from the “Edit form”.  
Anyway. If I put everything in one table, as you suggested, do you have any ideas how to define the List Fil range in the List Boxes. The amounts of people in the different locations are not fixed. At the moment I use this code as list fil range.
Offset (Location_A!$B$2;1;0;Engine!$AJ$5;10),were cell AJ in the Engine sheet contains this formula =Counta (Location_A!A1:A9914)-2.

Comment: What does the user form for editing the locations look like? Can you post an image of it?

Comment: I have added two images of the "Edit Form" where data can be edited and the person can be moved between the different locations. Its al in Swedish, hope you understand something anyway...
The "Edit Form" is a copy of the " Registration Form". They are the same, but they have different layout and some of the controls are disabled in one or the other . This is why I think it's so strange that the "Registration" works flawless, but when saving to another sheet in the  "Edit form", Excel crashes.
Many thanks again for taking time.